# JavaScript official keywords shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I've seen something similar to this code in the Google API JavaScript, I mean the r=Array part. Here is an example of what they have done:

```
var r = Array;
var t = new r('sdsd' , 'sdsd');
alert(t[0]);
```

Few questions about this:

1. Is it legal to write like this and won't cause any problems?
2. I can do something similar with other keywords like ´For´ loop or with the ´this´ keyword?
3. Can I have article about this JavaScript official keyword shortcuts etc..?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Array` is an identifier name (not a keyword), `for` is a reserved keyword - there's a difference. `this` is a reserved word, but you can still assign it to other variables (it's an exception - it's the only keyword that represents an expression, and not statement or operator syntax).

Comment: Keywords and reserved words in general are listed here: http://es5.github.com/#x7.6.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. `for` - no.  `this` - yes.

You can store references to any JavaScript object in a variable.  `String`, `Array`, `Object`, etc. are [JavaScript objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htbw4ywd%28VS.94%29.aspx) that are built-in to the language.  `for`, `if`, `while`, etc. are are [JavaScript statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xcfcb93%28VS.94%29.aspx), and cannot be stored or referenced any other way.

You can do it the other way around as well (and really mess yourself up in the process):

```
Array = 0;
var myArray = new Array("a", "b", "c"); // throws error
```

This is easily undone like this:

```
Array = [].constructor;
```

**Edit:** Being able to assign the value of `this` to a variable is essential when nesting functions that will execute in a different scope:

```
function Widget() {
    var that = this;
    this.IsThis = function() {
        return isThis();
    };
    function isThis() {
        return that == this;
    }
}
new Widget().IsThis(); // false!
```

Maybe not the best example, but illustrates losing scope.

You cannot reassign the value of `this`:

```
function doSomething() {
    this = 0; // throws error
}
```

Comment: can you give me example of "this" reference? and is this  technique got name of something that i can read about?

Comment: @gilly3 `for`, `if`, etc. are not statements *per se* but rather tokens (terminals to be precise) which are part of the syntax of statements.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Please expound further... The ecmascript specification refers to `for` as the ["for Statement"](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.6.3).

Comment: @MorSela - See the edit to my answer for an example of storing a reference to `this` in a variable.

Comment: @gilly3 The for statement is this: `for ( ExpressionNoInopt ; Expressionopt ; Expressionopt) Statement`. It consists of (1) the `for` terminal, (2) the `(` terminal, (3) the `ExpressionNoInopt` nonterminal, (4) the `;` terminal, etc. The `for` keyword is only one of the terminals that form the for statement. A keyword is not a statement, but merely a token. A statement consists of multiple tokens, it's a sequence of tokens.

Comment: @gilly3 Read chapter 5 of the spec: http://es5.github.com/#x5 It explains terms like grammars, productions, terminals and non-terminals.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Ok, I see what you are saying.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

That works because `Array` is an object. You can do that with any object. For example, the `Date` object:

```
var d = Date;
console.log((new d()).getTime()); //Prints time
```

You *cannot* do that for keywords such as `for` or `while` because they are language constructs that will be recognised by the interpreter.

You can do it with `this`:

```
document.getElementById("b").onclick = function() {
    var x = this; //this holds a reference to the DOM element that was clicked
    x.value = "Clicked!";
}
```

In fact, that can be very useful sometimes (to keep a reference to `this` so you can access it from an anonymous inner function for example). This also works because, to put it simply, `this` will be a reference to an object.